# std::array<const T, n> vs std::array<T, n> overload resolution

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++14, c++17

The problem seems simple enough yet I'm only able to solve it the "ugly" way. Here's a short code:

```
#include <array>
struct A {
    A(int , int = 0) {}
    A(std::array<const int, 2>) {}
    //A(std::array<int, 2>) {}
};

int main(){
    std::array<int, 2> a = {0};
    const A x(a);
    return 0;
}
```

As-is the compiler is trying to use the `A(int, int = 0)` constructor and, of course, fails the `std::array` to `int` conversion.

Commenting out the first constructor gives a clear compiler error that `std::array<int, 2>` cannot be automatically converted into it's const counterpart. And this is somewhat puzzling to me as I'd expect a non-const to const conversion to be "trivial".

The issue is resolved by introducing a third constructor (commented out in the code sample) but that looks like an overkill.

My questions are:

1. Why is the non-const to const conversion not done automatically here?
2. Can this be "fixed" without introducing the third, non-const version of the constructor?
3. Changing the constructor to accept `gsl::span` instead of `std::array` also helps, yet also feels like an overkill as well

I'm compiling on MSVC 2017 15.7.4 using the C++17 setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Why is the non-const to const conversion not done automatically here?

Because `std::array<T, Dim> const` and `std::array<T const, Dim>` are different types and, how say my clang++, "no known conversion from '`array<int, [...]>`' to '`array<const int, [...]>`'"

> 2) Can this be "fixed" without introducing the third, non-const version of the constructor?

What about a template constructor

```
template <typename T>
A (std::array<T, 2> const &) {}
```

where `T` can match both `int` and `int const` ?

If you want impose that `T` is only `int` or `int const` (and not, by example, `long const`) you can do it through SFINAE with something as

```
template <typename T>
A (std::array<T, 2>,
   std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T const, int const>{}> * = nullptr)
 { }
```

So you can have

```
std::array<int, 2> a = {{0}};
std::array<int const, 2> b = {{0}};
std::array<long const, 2> c = {{0}};

const A x(a);  // compile
const A y(b);  // compile
const A z(c);  // compilation error
```

> 3) Changing the constructor to accept gsl::span instead of std::array also helps, yet also feels like an overkill as well

Sorry but I don't understand the third question (?) (and I don't know `gls::span`)

Comment: "Under the hood" the template will still produce 2 distinct functions (could be inlined, of course) so that solution hides the problem. Still a +1 from me since it is "clearer" than what I had :)

Comment: `gsl::span` is a "safe buffer" from the Guidelines Support Library https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL - an initiative lead by Bjarn to help developers minimize silly mistakes in their code and to help static code analysis tools, like the one (now) integrated into MSVC